# I am getting this error when I run run my express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am getting type error on Express Router middleware. Below are the codes and error mentioned. Any help?

The app is running fine, but when I hit URL in the browser, it through below error in console.

Here is my app.js file

**app.js**

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use("view engine", "ejs");
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  // res.send("Hello");
  var today = new Date();
  console.log(date);
  var currentDay = today.getDay();
  var day = "";
  console.log(currentDay);
  if (currentDay === 6 || currentDay === 0) {
    // res.send("yay! it's weekend. ");
    day = "weekend";
  } else {
    day = "weekday";

  }
  res.render("list", {
    kindOfDay: day
  });
});



app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("server started at port 3000");
});
```

Here is list.ejs file

**list.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>to do list</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>It's a <%= kindOfDay %>!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**error**

```
E:\todoList-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
          throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but 
    got a ' + gettype(fn))
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string    
    at Function.use (E:\todoList-v1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (E:\todoList-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.use (E:\todoList-v1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\todoList-v1\app.js:6:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)       
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
```

**I got above error as above**

Answer (score 3):

This

```
app.use("view engine", "ejs");
```

should be

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

`app.use` is there to apply middleware functions. To set express variables, you need to use `app.set`. That is why you are getting the error because `app.use` expects a middleware function/callback such as `function(req, res) {...}`